# Matchbox recommender in azure machine learning workspace

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

The matchbox recommender available in http://studio.azureml.net doesn't seem to have a counterpart in http://ml.azure.com (which it appears is the newer portal for azure ml). Here only the plain SVD recommender is available, which doesn't take user or item features. This is a feature takeaway from the matchbox.

Is there an ETA when matchbox would be made available in the azure machine learning services? Either via SDK or designer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

we don't have a plan to bring back the matchbox yet. If you are looking for recommender algorithms, this repo could be a good reference for best practices: https://github.com/Microsoft/Recommenders. Please let me know if this can unblock you or if you are looking for specific thing in matchbox.

Comment: Thanks I have seen the GitHub and its very useful.

Comment: On the azure offering, will there be no recommender splitter either? In what kind of recommendation scenarios should the canned random splitter be used?

Comment: We can get you connected with the author of this repo and discuss how we can enable the recommender splitter module in designer. Please feel free to reach out to me via: luzhan@microsoft.com.

Comment: @Darshat in case you are interested in designer, here there is a tutorial on how to integrate any algo from Recommenders into AzureML designer https://github.com/microsoft/recommenders/blob/master/notebooks/00_quick_start/sar_movieratings_with_azureml_designer.ipynb

Comment: @hoaphumanoid - thanks for the pointer and I will try that out.